# redirect status 301 is not working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a number of redirects like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
get 'pages/teachers_tour', to: redirect('/pages/teachers-tour', status: 301)
```

i.e trying to have my urls more google friendly.

This works in test and development mode (although I am losing my query parameters)

However when I put this live on production I see a page not found error.

I do use a CDN on production but the problem also occurs on staging which has no CDN. I was able to fix this temporarily on production using the CDN (Cloudflare).

How do I permanently fix this? Is there a way of doing this change of url name such that the query parameter will be transfered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was due to this statement in the `config/routes.rb` file

```
# must be on last line
match '*unmatched', to: 'application#route_not_found', via: :all if Rails.env.production?
```

Unfortunately I did not convey the importance of this being the last line to all the team, so the redirects were placed after this line and so never reached.

At the time, I knew it was a poor thing to do from a software engineering perspective, but take no pleasure in proving myself right.

Answer (score 1):

`i.e trying to have my urls more google friendly.`

If it's just to this reason I will advise you to use `as` instead of a redirection. It's going just to change the slug displayed.

**Edit to be clearer:**

`get 'pages/teachers_tour', as: 'teachers-tour', to: "pages#teachers_tour"`

I guess it will be fix also your parameter issue.